# Android Studio GPS "libmagtsync.so"

Tags: android-gps

I want to retrieve the GPS position of my cell phone. Using Android Studio,
the position is not displayed. In Logcat, I have these messages in red:
E/QT: [QT]file does not exist
E/FBI: Can't load library: dlopen failed: library "libmagtsync.so" not found
E/OpenGLRenderer: Device claims wide gamut support, cannot find matching config, error = EGL_SUCCESS
Does anyone know how to do this, please?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for retrieving the GPS position in Android Studio, you need to make sure you've added the necessary permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Include the following line:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Also, check if you're requesting the necessary permissions at runtime, especially if your app targets Android 6.0 or higher. You can use some code to do this:

```java
// Inside your activity or fragment
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
} else {
    // Permission already granted, you can retrieve the location
    // You can use methods like LocationManager or FusedLocationProviderClient to get the location
}
```

Now, onto those red error messages. It seems like they might not be directly related to the GPS problem. These errors are more about missing files and libraries in your application. Ensure that your project setup is correct and that you've included all the necessary dependencies.